# Django Multiple User type and extra fields

Tags: python, django, multiple-users

I have a project. My project has multiple user types and every type has different fields.
For example user types are admin, teacher,student,

admin area does not need any changes,
teacher fields-> branch (mathematics, physics teacher), mentor, mentor student(relationship)
student fields->school name, score, school number ....
I want use admin panel and for example i want to create student in one page
How should i design my model?
if its impossible ,
what could be the alternatives

Thank you for your assistance

i tried abstractuser and proxy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.